# Batch File path with an [at] @ sign

Tags: batch-file, special-characters

I am trying to run a script to clear out the recycle bin on a QNAP NAS periodically.
The problem is the path for the recycle bin on the NAS includes an [at] sign:
"\nas01\SQLBackup\@Recycle" (Had to use double slash here to get it to display correctly)

Can someone please point me in the right direction as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**Batch File Code**

```
@ECHO ON
NET USE X: "\\nas01\SQLBackup\@Recycle"
forfiles /p "X:\" /s /m * /c "cmd /c del @path"
NET USE X: /delete
PAUSE
```

**Output**

```
C:\Windows\system32>NET USE X: "\\nas01\SQLBackup\@Recycle"
The command completed successfully.


C:\Windows\system32>forfiles /p "X:\" /s /m * /c "cmd /c del @path"
ERROR: Invalid argument/option - '@path'.
Type "FORFILES /?" for usage.

C:\Windows\system32>NET USE X: /delete
X: was deleted successfully.


C:\Windows\system32>PAUSE
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you get the error is due to the double quotes around the path, where backslash is present. The backslash escapes the last double quote. You should either use:

```
forfiles /p "X:" /s /m * /c "cmd /c del @path"
```

or

```
forfiles /p X:\ /s /m * /c "cmd /c del @path"
```

anyway, I would not use `forfiles` at all here. You can quite simply use `del /s`:

```
net use X: "\\nas01\SQLBackup\@Recycle"
pushd "x:\">nul 2>&1 && del /Q /S *.* || echo X:\ Not available.
popd
net use X: /delete
pause
```

Quite simply, we attempt `pushd` to `x:\` if not available, it will fail with a message, if available it will `del /s` everything on `X:\` where `/s` is basically recursive search throughout the root of `X:\` in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

The `@`-symbol in your path does not cause the error. It is the backslash in:

```cmd
forfiles /p "X:\" /s /m * /c "cmd /c del @path"
```

that unintentionally escapes the closing quote (this is specific to [`forfiles`](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html)!). To avoid that, simply append a `.` to the path, like:

```cmd
forfiles /p "X:\." /s /m * /c "cmd /c del @path"
```

The `.` means *current directory*, so in a path it does not change anything, hence `X:\` equals `X:\.`, and `D:\some\.\path` equals `D:\some\path`. Of course, you could just remove the quotes around `X:\` in your particular situation, but appending `.` is a general solution that even works with a relative path like `X:` (meaning the current directory of drive `X:`), and removal of quotes introduces problems with paths containing <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>.

---

By the way, are you aware that `forfiles` returns both files *and* directories, and that [`del`](https://ss64.com/nt/del.html) is there to delete just files, and there is [`rd`](https://ss64.com/nt/rd.html) to delete directories?

So to ensure to handle only files, use this:

```cmd
forfiles /S /P "X:\." /M * /C "cmd /C if @isdir==FALSE del @path"
```

And to ensure to handle only directories, use this:

```cmd
forfiles /S /P "X:\." /M * /C "cmd /C if @isdir==TRUE rd /S /Q @path"
```

Of course you can handle both, if you want:

```cmd
forfiles /S /P "X:\." /M * /C "cmd /C if @isdir==TRUE (rd /S /Q @path) else (del @path)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice aschipfl.  I ended up going with Gerhard's advice to simplify the process and just use a del command.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `PushD`, it will create a temporary drive map, *(allocated in available reverse alphabetical order, `Z:`..`A:`)*, and will then use that new drive. For that reason you should be able to do this without using `net.exe`.

Example:

```bsh
@PushD "\\nas01\SQLBackup\@Recycle" 2> NUL && (RD /S /Q . 2> NUL & PopD)
```

This example uses `RD` to `R`emove the `D`irectory instead of your used `Del` command. When the target directory is the current working directory, it cannot be removed, *(returning an error message)*, however its contents will be. The code above redirects the error message to the `NUL` device, so that it is not output.